# yes command printing null at the prompt

Tags: bash

I have to add a remote host as a datasource to my RHEL server, and while connecting, it asks if i want to trust the certificate of the host. I tried to use the yes command, but at the prompt where it asks this, only null is printed and the command exits.

I type: `yes|datasource add <hostname>`and the output is

```
Do you want to trust this certificate(y/n) 
null
#
```

the `datasource add` command was built in-house. Could this have something to do with why `yes` behaves thus?

Comment: the `yes` doesn't behave like that. It's the `datasource` command that behaves like that and prints the null. You'll have to figure out why, we don't know how that command works.

Comment: What normally happens at that prompt if you type `y` and hit enter?

Comment: It works fine if you manually type a y.

Comment: Try sending a single `y` instead of many: `echo 'y' | datasource add <hostname>`

Comment: echo y results in the same issue. It prints null and exits.

Comment: Then i guess you're out of luck. Your program/script might not be reading from stdin but from some other channel.

Comment: If `echo` and `yes` lead to the same result, the problem is almost certainly in the `datasource` program rather than either `echo` or `yes`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `datasource` program must need to read the `y` from a terminal, so you will need to make it believe its standard input is a terminal.  You can do it with `script -c`.  For example:

```
echo y | script -c 'datasource add <hostname>' /dev/null
```

The `/dev/null` is used to stop `script` saving the dialog to any file.